# JavaScript error: dataDetailSkill[item].data.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite

```
export default function DetailSkill() {
const { item } = useParams();
return (
    <div className="w-screen min-h-screen flex flex-col p-[30px] bg-slate-100  overflow-hidden">
        <Header title={item} />
        <div className="mt-12 flex flex-col gap-4">
            <img src={dataDetailSkill[item].bannerImg} alt="" className="w-full h-[200px] object-cover rounded-lg" />
            <p>{dataDetailSkill[item].description}</p>
            <div className="flex flex-col gap-4">
                {dataDetailSkill[item].data.map((v) => {
                    return <SkillCard title={item} content={v.title} img={v.img} link={v.github} key={v.id} />;
                })}
            </div>
        </div>
        <ModalMenu />
    </div>
);
```

}

what's wrong with the code. chrome says dataDetailSkill[item].data.map is not a function. I use Vite React. sorry newbie

dataDetailSkill.js
I want to do mapping on the dataDetailSkill.js file but there is an error

```js
export default {
    html: {
        description: "Membuat website sederhana",
        bannerImg: "https://images.pexels.com/photos/4439901/pexels-photo-4439901.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1",
        data: {
            id: 1,
            title: "Membuat website landing page",
            github: "",
            img: "https://images.pexels.com/photos/114907/pexels-photo-114907.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1",
        },
    },
    frontend: {
        description: "Membuat website dengan React JS",
        bannerImg: "https://images.pexels.com/photos/4439901/pexels-photo-4439901.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1",
        data: {
            id: 1,
            title: "Membuat website film",
            github: "",
            img: "https://images.pexels.com/photos/114907/pexels-photo-114907.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1",
        },
    },
    it: {
        description: "Sertifikat Kepelatihan saya dalam IT",
        bannerImg: "https://images.pexels.com/photos/4439901/pexels-photo-4439901.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1",
        data: {
            id: 1,
            title: "IT Support",
            github: "",
            img: "https://images.pexels.com/photos/196644/pexels-photo-196644.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1",
        },
    },
    web: {
        description: "Project membuat web design",
        bannerImg: "https://images.pexels.com/photos/4439901/pexels-photo-4439901.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1",
        data: {
            id: 1,
            title: "Project saya",
            github: "",
            img: "https://images.pexels.com/photos/196644/pexels-photo-196644.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1",
        },
    },
};
```

I've followed the tutorial on YouTube but the error still persists

Comment: Can you provide full code, please?

Comment: I've given you the complete code

Comment: Based on what you provided i assume that you're trying to use `.map` on object, not array which will not work at all. Can you add `console.log(dataDetailSkill[item].data)` and see if it is an array or not?

Comment: it's done. I didn't add `[{}]` after `data: `. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

The object does not have a map function, so you need to change it to list.

data : {} => data : [{}]